# Add a second target in the Xcode 5 project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode5

Please help me to add second target in Xcode 5 , I need to build two different app like "app 1" and "app 2". app 1 should point to url 1 and app 2 should point to url 2 .

Also I should be able to install both the app on same device at same time.

I am using Xcode 5.1.

I have also tried to duplicating existing target and renamed it and changed product name and bundle identifier, But it iss over writing the app 1 when I install app 2.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps to add new target in Xcode 5.1

```
1) Open Xcode and go to File->New-> Target
2) Choose a target for your new target and Tap on "Next"
3) Enter the Product Name (Target name) and Tap on Finish
```

Comment: I need the copy of existing target.

Comment: Ya, I duplicated it and renamed , changed product name , bundle identifier . When I install it over writing the old app.

Comment: if just duplicate the target and rename it is not enough you should also add Info.Plist file and set it for the new target.

Comment: @user3317914 ...and you need to change the bundle id of new target as well, of course, because iOS automatically updates the application with the same bundle id, when a new build is deployed.